# two dimensional array, methods and variables

Tags: java, arrays

Seems like my main variables **n** and **m** cant be changed via method dimensions. Console says that there is a problem at method **create** in this line **a [ i ][ j ] = unos.nextInt();** but
if i change this line **private int[ ][ ] a = new int[n][m];** and put any number like [3][4], the program works, but with [n][m] it does not, can u help me guys, whats wrong with this code. CONSOLE: a[1][1]=Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
   Thanks in advance..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrica {
private int n, m;
private Scanner unos = new Scanner(System.in);

public void dimensions() {
    System.out.print("n: ");
    n = unos.nextInt();
    System.out.print("m: ");
    m = unos.nextInt();

}

private int[][] a = new int[n][m]; // if i put [2][2] or any other number, instead [n][n], program works

public void create() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            System.out.print("a[" + (i + 1) + "][" + (j + 1) + "]=");
            a[i][j] = unos.nextInt(); // console points that this is the problem
        }
}

public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Thrasher why did you edit this to add all the unneeded spaces?  This is not typical Java style and just looks weird.

Comment: @Thrasher I don't recommend doing this in the future.  Your personal style is your business, but there are some fairly well-established standards  for Java spacing (not all of which I like, but I live with them), and I think it's best to work within that on a site with tons of readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
private int[][] a = new int[n][m];
```

is being executed before the code in the constructor is executed.  That is, the `new` is being done when `n` and `m` haven't been set, and at this point they've been initialized to 0 by default.  So it's allocating an array with no rows or columns.

To fix this, change the above to

```
private int[][] a;
```

and initialize it in the constructor, after `n` and `m` have been set:

```
a = new int[n][m];
```

For more information on the order in which things are executed when an instance is created, see [this section of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Answer (score 0):

Like @ajb said, initialize the array after the variables `n` & `m` have obtained there values using the `Scanner`. You can do this in the `dimensions()` method.

```
public void dimensions() {
    System.out.print("n: ");
    n = unos.nextInt();
    System.out.print("m: ");
    m = unos.nextInt();
    a = new int[n][m]; //Add the following line.
}
```

Comment: hmm, i thought its all about the order, didnt know about that kind of priority.. learned something new

Comment: It is not always about the order in which you write your code. Java is a fully object oriented language and when you run the code, no matter where you have created your class level variables (whether they are the first few lines of code in your class or the last) the variables will be created before the actual code execution takes place.